# Help me change TextView color dynamically?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how to change the color of a TextView dynamically.  It seems there is some stuff out there but now quite what I'm looking for.. what i'm doing here is iterating an array and if its "+" i want the text to be greem if its "-" i want the text to be red, the problem is that i'm getting null pointer error at ct.setTextColor(.....) anyone have any idea why?

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/bt"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="-"

        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code snippit

```
    int c = count; 
    ind = (count);
    j=0;
    TextView ct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pm);
    funkAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowneg, R.id.pm));
    String[] tmpAry= new String[count]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < ind; i = i+2){
         tmpAry[j] = dataAryArray[i];

        if (tmpAry[j].equals("-")){
        funkAdapter.add(tmpAry[j]);
        ct.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            funkAdapter.add(tmpAry[j]);
            ct.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        j++;
    }
    setListAdapter(funkAdapter);
```

Comment: add the stack trace of your exception plz ,

Comment: This may seem ridiculous.. but how do i obtain this? logcat?

Comment: You can get a stack trace by using the DDMS in your tools folder located where you got your Android SDK. Launch the DDMS with the phone plugged in and click on the red (E) symbol for errors.

Comment: if you use Eclipse IDE , go to Window ==> Show View ==> Other ==> Android ==> LogCat

Answer (score 1):

If this code snippet above is what you copied-and-pasted out of your onCreate() method, then the main problem I see why it's giving you a null pointer error is because you haven't set the current activity's view to the XML layout with all the stuff in it. In other words, findViewById() doesn't know where you find those ID's you're referring to. Try adding this to the first line of your onCreate(), or anywhere before you call findViewById():

`setContentView(R.id.yourLinearLayout);`

Comment: he said that the nullPointerException is giving at ct.setTextColor() .. if he didnt specify the Content of hie activity , the nullpointerException will be at `ct = (TextView) findViewById(...)`

Comment: No that's not true Houcine. If you don't initialize the setContentView() correctly, findViewById() will simply return null when it can't find the view referred to in the current activity. It isn't until he tries to use that view (ie. call ct.setTextColor()) will it crash because that TextView is actually null.

Comment: i know that, but the progamm signale the exception at ct.setTextColor() , if the TextView is null , i think the exception will be signaled at findViewById() ??

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm trying to say... findViewById() attempts to find a view within the given layout. If it isn't found, it won't throw an exception, instead, it'll just return null. It isn't until you try to use that object will it crash. Trust me, you can test it out for yourself.